# Is there a way to expand acronyms and glossary terms in the LaTeX source using the glossaries package?

Tags: glossaries, miktex2.9, journal-publishing

I am using the glossaries package to print acronyms and some terms in a LaTeX manuscript. The problem is that the publisher is having trouble with those entries. It is a little difficult to get detailed information from them, but as far as I can tell, they are using MikTeX 2.9 and something called GrindEQ to convert the LaTex documents to Word.

The glossaries entries are simply not compiling in their system. For example, if I have an entry

```
\newglossaryentry{aidx}
{
  name=acoustic index,
  plural=acoustic indices,
  description={DEF} 
}
```

and it is referenced in my LaTeX file as

```
\Glspl{aidx} are valuable tools for measuring and tracking changes in biodiversity.
```

it shows up in their compiled text as

```
aidx are valuable tools for measuring and tracking changes in biodiversity.
```

The source compiles as expected (and expands to `Acoustic indices are valuable tools for measuring and tracking changes in biodiversity.`) both on my computer and on Overleaf, but I have no control over the publishers process.

So, what I would like to do is to correctly expand all of the glossary and acronym entries in the LaTeX source so that the source reads `Acoustic indices are valuable...` instead of `\Glspl{aidx} are valuable...`. This way the publisher will not have to deal with the `glossaries` package at all.

Is there a way to do this automatically? I'm imagining you could run `pdflatex` (and `makeglossaries` or `makeindex` and then have a separate shell script that processes the glossary/acronym files and replaces the text in the original `.tex` files. Does something like that already exist, or am I going to have to do this by hand?

Thanks!

Comment: If MiKTeX 2.9 is true, it must be a very old version: https://miktex.org/announcement/future-miktex-2-9 . // Do you provide your text and glossary in one or in two files? // What would MWEs (minimal working examples) look like? // Sometimes packages influence each other. What's the complete Preamble in your document?

Comment: For our info: GrindEQ: https://www.grindeq.com/index.php?p=latex2word&lang=en

Comment: Hello, sadly, there is no such thing that would expand glossaries package definitions and modify your source. I have been facing the same issue when converting from tex to docx with pandoc. I ended up creating a python script to substitute (expand) glossaries commands to theire definitions and ran that with pythontex.

Comment: @MS-SPO The document is in many different files (all of the glossary entries are in their own file). The preamble is pretty extensive, so an MWE isn't so easy to put together (specially because It works for me, so the "working" part of that relies on a setup that I don't have access to).

Comment: @TomášKruliš do you have a copy of that python script online somewhere that I could take a look at? I'm well versed in python, but don't have any experience with pythontex.